# Change Gmail account display name on top right menu

Tags: gmail, account-management

I've just created a new Gmail account, but I entered a wrong Last and First name.

By the account edit info feature I fixed that information, but in the top right drop down menu I still see the wrong display name.

How could I fix it?

Here are some screenshots:

[image: Account detail edit dialog (G+)]

[image: Top Right popup menu]

Comment: Have you tried logging out and back in? And cleaning cache/cookies in between?

Comment: Sure, I did it many times. I also tried to change browser in order to avoid cookie issues!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The change is not instant. When you try to change your name, the dialog box states:

> Please note that it may take some time for this change to be fully applied.

[image]

Comment: I didn't read this alert, sorry. So, I'll check it later. Thank you very much!

Comment: I confirm that the account name has been updated, thank you!